# Is it possible to change the side a div is set to float to after it resizes?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Say I have 2 divs set up something like this

```
|------------------------------|

| div1 ------------------ div2 |

|------------------------------|


.div1{
    float:left;
}

.div2{
    float:right;
}
```

as I understand, they'll move when resized, but div2 will continue to float to the right:

```
|--------------------|

| div1 ------------- |

|--------------- div2|
```

Does css support change the alignment to the left?

```
|---------------------|

| div1 -------------- |

| div2 ---------------|
```

I can't quite get the terminogy correct enough to find the answer on google.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Downvoting because of lack of understanding hurts more than it helps when people ask questions. I like how LGSon provided a link to help the Auther ask questions in a better way.

Comment: @bstory based on what you conclude that people are *downvoting because of lack of understanding?* : hover the downvote button and read its tooltip to understand the correct reason of downvoting

Comment: @bstory for the record, I didn't find that link entirely helpful as I'm looking for clarity on how a property works.

Comment: @dumbdumbbadatthis The link I provided doesn't tell how a property works, it tell how to post a proper question. Depending on how your  code looks like there might be several answer, but only one good, so posting good question is more beneficial for you than for us.

Comment: @LGSon my point is that I don't have a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example", I have a concept that I need help understanding in order to create my "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" of the behaviour I'm describing. This community is so heavily policed to deny flexibility that it bums me out sometimes... I'm just trying to ask for help.

Comment: @dumbdumbbadatthis Then you might not understand what a _MCVE_ is. It is not the solution, it is the code you have so far, that produce the issue you have, and the one you want to behave different.

Comment: @TemaniAfif He stated that he googled but didn't understand the terminology needed to solve the problem. All I'm pointing out is that downvoting is more discouraging for people who are trying to understand a concept. Not everyone is as familiar with development as you likely are.

Comment: @bstory so I invite you to learn how StackOverflow work as you seems to not understand the purpose of asking a good and clear question because we don't downvote *the* person but *the* question and again the downvote reason is on the tooltip [This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)] .. being a Guru or beginner has nothing to do here, it's all about *how* to write a good question. We don't help people, we answer clear question with clear answer to build a great Q&A website for any future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do requires the use of a media query. 
This is real simple.

In your css you will structure your styles in the following way.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

```
@media (min-width: 576px) { .div1 {float:left}; .div2 {float:left} }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { .div1 {float:left}; .div2 {float:left} }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { .div1 {float:left}; .div2 {float:right} }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { .div1 {float:left}; .div2 {float:right} }
```

You Tagged bootstrap-4 so here is the documentation for how to use this inside the framework.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/

```
<div class="float-sm-left">Float left on viewports sized SM (small) or wider</div><br>
<div class="float-md-left">Float left on viewports sized MD (medium) or wider</div><br>
<div class="float-lg-left">Float left on viewports sized LG (large) or wider</div><br>
<div class="float-xl-left">Float left on viewports sized XL (extra-large) or wider</div><br>
```

Apply the classes you need based on the view width and your good to go.

```
<div class="float-sm-left">content here</div>
<div class="float-sm-left float-md-right">content here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need media queries ?

```
@media (max-width:1024px) {
  .div2{
    float:none;
  }
}
```

more on here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for this.the flex wrap will shift the second div down

```
<style>
.parent
   {
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:space-between;
flex-wrap:wrap;
    }
.div1,.div2{
 width:46%;}
</style>
<div class="parent">
<div class="div1">
</div>
<div class="div2">
</div>
```